# Generate multiple Barcode or QR Codes Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a simple csv file with some data as shown:

[image]

I'm trying to get my script to read the csv file and generate the barcodes (same file would be idea, but at least if I can get multiple files I can create another script to combine them).

Here is my script:

```
f = open('bc.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f)
for serial in csv_f:
    data = (''.join(serial))
    print(data)
    Code39 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code39')
    code39 = Code39(data, add_checksum=False)
    code39.save('barcodetest')
```

It runs, but only generates the last code. I know I'm missing something here that will generate multiple files with multiple names, but I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate the filename, for example:

```
f = open('bc.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
next(csv_f)
for id, serial in enumerate(csv_f):
    data = (''.join(serial))
    print(data)
    Code39 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code39')
    code39 = Code39(data, add_checksum=False)
    code39.save('barcodetest' + str(id))
```